# redirecting from www to non-www urls with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am redirecting an application with following code on my .htaccess file, the page is supposed to do the followings:

1. replace .php extension with .html
2. redirect from http to https
3. redirect from www to non-www urls

The extension .html is working fine and it is redirecting from http to https but the issue is to redirect from www to non-www, it is working properly on main url but when there is reference to a file then it is not working.

Say when i write www.ntestechnologies.com i get my desire url that is https://ntestechnologies.com but when i write www.ntestechnologies.com/index.html i get this https://www.ntestechnologies.com/index.html i don't need the www in this url as well please guide me, here is the code on htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.ntestechnologies\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/ntestechnologies\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```

Comment: If you want to rewrite all *www.* urls why not just write **RewriteRule (.*)** instead of *RewriteRule ^/?$*? You're not even using the backreference ($1) in the substitution URL because you're not capturing any results.

Comment: I also recommend that you add the following condition to your HTTPS check (or replace it entirely) as I've seen the *%{HTTPS}* variable being unstable. **RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ [OR]**. The OR flag means that if either conditions are true (not using https) then do the rewrite

Comment: the code is copy and paste and I am not an expert of .htacess and apache can you please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one `RewriteEngine On`.

You cannot use `HTTP_HOST` or `REQUEST_URI` in a `RewriteRule`. If you need to capture these values, you must do so in a [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)(.+)
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule .* https://%1/$0 [R,L]
```

This removes the leading `www`, if present. At the same time, it redirects to HTTPS.

Comment: The script work for me for the first time on any browser but if you try for the second time on the same browser it just re-direct to https but www is not removed.

Comment: Here you're splicing together both actions http -> https and www to -> non-www. I doubt that's what he needs.

Comment: @MIrfan For me, it works any number of times. What I forgot, is to cover the case, when https is already enabled. I added the additional rule needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirects from HTTP to HTTPS. We use %{SERVER_PORT} as it's more reliable than %{HTTPS}
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

# Redirects www.example.com/... to example.com/...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [nc]
```